# Why is my initial state value in useState undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the following code. I use a function to get an initial value for a state variable. But, when I code for console log in the function and after the function is run (b, and c), the nextAppointment state is not being set. Help!

I added a random variable cow that is set correctly using the same function, to show that my source data is alright.

```
const getNextAppointment = appointments => {
  let currentTime = moment();
  let nextAppt = appointments.find(a => a.AppointmentDateTime > currentTime);
  console.log('B', nextAppt);
  return nextAppt;
};

function AppointmentListByDate(props) {
  let appointments = props.appointments.sort((a, b) => a.AppointmentDateTime - b.AppointmentDateTime);
  console.log('A');
  var [nextAppointment, setNextAppointment] = React.useState(getNextAppointment(appointments));
  console.log('C', nextAppointment);
  var cow = getNextAppointment(appointments);
  console.log('D', cow);
  render(<div>Hello World</div>);
}
```

UPDATE: changed `a => a.AppointmentDateTime > currentTime` to `a => a.AppointmentDateTime.isAfter(currentTime)` in the find method without positive results.

Comment: Based on the given it, it appears that there's no element in the `appointments` array that satisfies the condition `a.AppointmentDateTime > currentTime`. Make sure that coercion to numbers (due to the `>` operator) isn't leading to a loss of data. What is the type of `AppointmentDateTime`?

Comment: Maybe it is because of the callback method in the find function  in the getNextAppointment method?

Comment: What do you mean by the callback method in the find function?

Comment: There are elements in appointments that satisfy. You see that the B console results in an appointment object, while the C console does not. I also added a random variable "cow" to show that it is being set correctly when not using "useState"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue in the shared code but I can point 1 area which might be causing problem for you.

I guess it's the `moment()` which returns a date object. I am not sure whats the appointment format you have in `props`, so if you can share these details then probably I can share the whole code or just give it a try, it shouldn't be that complex.

I have created a demo without `moment`, which works fine.

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-davinci-quxz1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Also instead of directly putting the function in `useState`, try this

```js
  const initialNextAppointment = getNextAppointment(appointments);
  var [nextAppointment, setNextAppointment] = React.useState(
    initialNextAppointment
  );
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this codesandbox, it showed me that my problem could be in the List component getting appointments twice. First empty, then the list.. but for some reason the nextAppointment doesn't get updated the second time?

Comment: So it seems that .. the component that has AppointmentListByDate as a child, has a useState that is set as [] and then a one time useEffect(()=>{}, []); calls the API to setAppointments in the parent, which therefore passes these new appointments as a property to the child AppointmentListByDate.. but this child doesn't get completely recreated or anything.. and it still has the old values? https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-lumiere-j6582

Comment: @SweetTomato Updated the suggestion above, have a look. https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-grass-5bdil?file=/src/List.js